# почему ответ false?

Tags: javascript

```
function isTrue(){
       var a = ('false' == false);
       console.log(a);
};
isTrue();
```

Comment: А с чего бы `true`?

Comment: Потому, что `'false' != false`. С одной стороны строка, а с другой булево выражение.

Comment: Потому что при сравнении `String` и `Boolean` оба операнда приводятся к `Number`, после чего происходит само сравнение. `'false'` приводится к `NaN`, `false` - к `0`. А `NaN` не равно `0`.

Answer (score 0):

Проверим:

```
typeof('false'); // === 'string'
typeof(false); // === boolean
```

Comment: `[] == false`, при этом `typeof([]) // object`и `typeof(false); // === boolean` так что показывает твой ответ?

Comment: И что с того, что типы разные? `console.log("0" == false);` вполне себе выведет `true`, например.

Comment: В вопросе `==`, а не `===`. С чего бы типы тут сравнивать?